# For a continuous function f on open interval $(a,b)$, if $\lim_{a^{+}}f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{b^{-}}f(x)=-\infty$, prove it has at least one zero.

Tags: calculus

This is quite an obvious consequence to the intermediate value theorem, but I　was wondering if there was a more concrete way to prove it?(by using the definition of limits, and choosing some  $(c,d)$ in $(a,b)$? Just a hunch--it might not work)
I also have another generalization (an unproved hypothesis, actually)

For a continuous function $f:I\rightarrow R$, where I is an open interval $(a,b)$, if $\lim_{x\to a^{+}}f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to b^{-}}f(x)=-\infty$, then the equation $f(x)=x$ has at least one solution.

Comment: In fact, with your $f$, $f(x)=g(x)$ has a solution for any continuous $g$ with $\lim_{x\to a^+}g(x)<\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to b^-}g(x)>-\infty$

Comment: Nice! Is there a formal proof for that?

Answer (score 0):

Any proof of your result will either use the IVT or essentially prove the IVT.  In fact you can derive the IVT from your result.  Namely, suppose $g$ is a continuous function on a closed interval $[c,d]$, and $v$ any real number between $g(c)$ and $g(d)$.  We may assume wlog $g(c) > v > g(d)$ (otherwise replace $g$ by $-g$). Let $f(x) = g(x) - v$.  Extend $f$ continuously to the interval $(c-1,d+1)$ by taking $f(x) = f(c)/(x-c+1)$ for $c-1 < x < c$ and $f(x) = f(d)/(d+1-x)$ for $d < x < d+1$.  Your result implies there is some $x \in (c-1,d+1)$ with $f(x)=0$,
and thus $g(x) = v$, and it is easy to see $x \in [c,d]$.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by "concrete", but you can do it in a way that constructs such a zero:

We shall define two sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$, which shall converge exponentially quickly to a zero.

To do this, define $a_0 = a$ and $b_0 = b$, and for each $n$, define $c_n$ to be the midpoint of $a_n$ and $b_n$. Then we have three cases:

1. $f(c_n) = 0$. In this case, we have found a zero, and can set $a_k = b_k = c_n$ for all $k > n$.
2. $f(c_n) < 0$. Then set $a_{n+1} = c_n$ and $b_{n+1} = b_n$.
3. $f(c_n) > 0$. Then set $a_{n+1} = a_n$ and $b_{n+1} = c_n$.

In this way, we note that:

1. We always have $f(a_n) \leq 0$ (or $a_n = a$).
2. We always have $f(b_n) \geq 0$ (or $b_n = b$).
3. Both $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ converge (they're bounded and monotonic).
4. They converge to the same limit (call it $c$), since$(a_n - b_n) = 2^{-n}(b - a)$.
5. By (1), $f(c) \leq 0$.
6. By (2), $f(c) \geq 0$.
7. Hence, $f(c) = 0$.

And so we have found our zero, and have an exponentially fast algorithm for doing so.

For your generalisation (and any other generalisation of the form mentioned in the comments): just apply the result directly to $h: x \mapsto f(x) - x$ (or $f(x) - g(x)$ for the generalised version in the comments): $h$ is continuous since $f$ and $g$ are, $\lim\limits_{x \to a^+}h(x) = \lim\limits_{x \to a^+}f(x) - \lim\limits_{x \to a^+}g(x) = -\infty$ (since the latter limit is not $\infty$), and similarly $\lim\limits_{x\to b^-}h(x) = \infty$. The above then gives some $c$ such that $h(c) = 0$, and then $f(c) = g(c)$.

Answer (score 0):

Use argument by contradiction. Suppose $f(x)=x$ has no solution in $(a,b)$. Then either $f(x)<x$ or $f(x)>x$ for $x\in(a,b)$. If $f(x)<x$ for $x\in(a,b)$, one has
$$ f(x)<x<b, x\in(a,b)$$
which is against $\lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)=\infty$. If $f(x)>x$ for $x\in(a,b)$, one has
$$ f(x)>x>a, x\in(a,b)$$
which is against $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)=-\infty$. Thus $f(x)=x$ must have a solution in $(a,b)$.

Comment: Your " should be against " should be proved.